# echo background image with a value

Tags: php, css, echo

I echo out an image like that:

```
$newString = $thumbPre.'profilemain'.$thumbPost;
echo "<img src='http://render-api-us.worldofwarcraft.com/static-render/us/" . $newString. "' alt='error'>";
```

Now i want the image as a background-image, i tried it like that, but it doesn´t work:

```
echo '<div style="background-image:url('http://render-api-us.worldofwarcraft.com/static-render/us/" . $newString. "' alt='error');"></div>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, remove `alt='error'` because `background-image` does not have an `alt` parameter, `img` does (*you probably thought you could use that from your original code*). In trying to use that, your background will not show up.

And your background won't show unless you have content inside that div. I've added `Content` as an example.

```
echo '<div style="background-image:url(\'http://render-api-us.worldofwarcraft.com/static-render/us/' . $newString.'\');">Content</div>';
```

You either have to escape the encapsulating quotes, or remove them altogether.

```
echo '<div style="background-image:url(http://render-api-us.worldofwarcraft.com/static-render/us/' . $newString.');">Content</div>';
```

---

Error reporting would have also thrown you a parse error such as:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' alt='' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 2):

you need to use backslashes for nested apostrophes

```
echo '<div style="background-image:url(\'http://render-api-us.worldofwarcraft.com/static-render/us/' . $newString.'\' alt=\'error\');></div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is going to look super confusing but you need to 1, escape the quotes and 2, concatenate your path within that,

let me give you an example. I misread a bit of the question but this will serve you well moving forward especially for cleanliness sake

here is an example:

```
$imagePath ='PATH TO IMAGE HERE';
echo '<div style="background-image:url(\'' .$imagePath. '\')" >STUFF HERE </div>';
```